# Why does Google Sign-In for Android return a "sub" user identifier that differs from UserService.getCurrentUser() for hosted domain accounts?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-authentication

For Google Accounts that are **NOT** hosted domain accounts, the `sub` user identifier returned by https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth always matches the response from `UserService.getCurrentUser().getUserId()` as expected.

However for hosted domain accounts, the `sub` identifier doesn't match the response from `UserService.getCurrentUser().getUserId()`. How can we have a common user identifier for hosted domain accounts, regardless of whether the user signs in using Google Sign-In for Android Id Token or via the server-side UserService browser sign-in?

Comment: I can't comment on why they differ, however one fallback is to use the email address as a common Id for hosted domain accounts as idToken.getPayload().getEmail() should always match UserService.getCurrentUser().getEmail().

Comment: Email addresses for Google accounts, however, can change, so that's not a very reliable method of identifying users uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

As to why: I'm pretty sure that the discrepancy is an artifact of the fact that Google App Engine uses Google's own authentication/user account system directly, whereas Identity Kit is a separate project that integrates with multiple OAuth providers. In other words, they're separate projects that were at some point only loosely integrated.

To address the problem, my recommendation is to *not use* Google's native authentication API on App Engine and instead just use [Identity Toolkit Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/), which will of course use the same data and schema as the Android/iOS Identity objects. Just using Identity Toolkit like it's any other web application is pretty simple, and it's portable outside of GAE.

If Identity Toolkit was around when App Engine was created, maybe they would be automatically integrated and everything would just work. But I've found you can't really mix and match them; you pick one and stick with it.